# Como enviar um caractere especial para a view , asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-4

Tenho uma situação onde gostaria de posicionar a página na mesma posição do container onde estava antes de enviar o Get?

Exemplo :

```
<!-- ==== contato ==== -->
<div class="container" id="contato" name="contato">
    <div class="row">

            @Html.Partial("_PartialMensagens")
            @using (Html.BeginForm("CadastroContato", "Representante", FormMethod.Get))
            {
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ContatoNome" name="ContatoNome" required placeholder="Nome"><br />
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Telefone" name="Telefone" required placeholder="Celular"><br />
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ContatoCidade" name="ContatoCidade" required placeholder="Cidade  UF"><br>
                    <textarea rows="4" cols="30" name="Mensagem" id="Mensagem"  class="form-control" required placeholder="Mensagem..."></textarea>
                    <br>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Enviar</button>
                </div>
            </form>
            }
    </div><!-- row -->

</div><!-- container -->
<!-- ==== contato ==== -->
```

Eu precisaria retornar este caminho :
http://localhost:18568/Representante/Index/1#contato

Com este exemplo não funciona porque não reconhece o #

```
return RedirectToAction("index", "Representante", new { id = Session["IdPaginaUsuario"] + "^#contato" });
```

Comment: Acho que vai ter que trocar o `#` por `&#35;`

Comment: existe o UrlEncode ? para asp.net mvc

Comment: O que você quer dizer com *UrlEncode*?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Answer (score 0):

Tente utilizar o \# pois a Barra invertida informa ao seu framework que aquele é um texto e não um caractere reservado pela linguagem deixando o assim: "#contato" e só uma observação, você colocou um acento circunflexo no seu código em **^#contato** e talvez este seja seu problema, então acredito que nem precisará da barra invertida

```
return RedirectToAction("index", "Representante", new { id = Session["IdPaginaUsuario"] + "\#contato" });
```